# Understanding Content Type in http request and response

Tags: html, http, content-type

Hello can someone please explain me how do you set the `type` for a `request` and the type of the `response` given a `html` element ?

**Example**:

If i want to send a `form` that sends some `files` and a `POCO` and receives a `stream` i would use `type=multipart/form-data` ; would `type` in this case refer to the `request` or the expected response?

`<form type="multipart/form-data"><input type="file"></form>`

In this case the `type` refers clearly to the request.But then it means that the `server` that processes the request has to set the `response.type` to `application/octet-stream`.

So following this reason i thought that what you set in the `form` is the `request` type.

**However** then i can not understand this contradiction:

```
<a class="button" type="application/octet-stream"  href="http://localhost:5300/get" download>Click here for dld</a>
```

I could not get a file download until i didn't set the `type` of the **response** here.I tried setting the response type in the server but it did not work.So in this case here **type** refers to the `response` and not the `request`.

Can someone please shed some light? Is there a list with the `html` elements on 
what they refer by `type` ? (type of the `request` or the expected `response` ) ?

**PS**
 Long story short : why does `form` refer to the `request` by `type` and `a` refers to the `response`.How can one reason when he wants to send a request whose content is type `A` and his response is type `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But then it means that the server that processes the request has to set the response.type to application/octet-stream.

No. The server can respond with whatever type of content it wants to.

`application/octet-stream` is a pretty meaningless "Here is a stream of bytes". Normally you would want something that describes the actual content type of the response.

> Can someone please shed some light?

The `type` attribute on the `<a>` element refers to the *expected* response type. This allows a bot to avoid following the link if it expects to get a response it can't understand.

Since a link triggers a GET request, there is no request body to describe the type of anyway.

> Is there a list with the html elements on what they refer by type ?

The HTML spec describes the type attribute for each element it appears on. e.g. [script](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element) links to [this type](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-type).

---

> How can one reason when he wants to send a request whose content is type A and his response is type B

You almost never need to tell the client what type to expect, so just don't. Only worry about it when you are constructing HTTP requests with bodies.