# Using DropBox File Request API to Collect files

Tags: delphi, dropbox-api

I need to programmatically request some files and send files as a response. How can I create a file request ( https://www.dropbox.com/requests ) from Delphi through API so that 3rd parties can send requested files back to me with this kind of code;

```
procedure TDropbox.Upload(const AFileName: String);
const
  API_URL = 'https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/sandbox/';
var
  URL: String;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
  ShortFileName: String;
  https: TIdHTTP;
  SslIoHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket;
begin
  if not FileExists(AFileName) then
  begin
    raise EInOutError.CreateFmt('File %s not found', [AFileName]);
  end;

  ShortFileName := ExtractFileName(AFileName);
  URL := API_URL+ShortFileName
    + '?oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_consumer_key=' + FAppKey
    + '&oauth_token=' + FOAuth.AccessToken
    + '&oauth_signature=' + FAppSecret + '%26' + FOAuth.AccessTokenSecret;

  https := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    SslIoHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.Create(https);
    SslIoHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
    SslIoHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;

    https.IOHandler := SslIoHandler;
    Stream.LoadFromFile(AFileName);

    https.Post(URL, Stream);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Stream);
    FreeAndNil(https);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It's HTTP, so every request (in this case via `POST`) will get a response. The latter will identify itself on how to be interpreted - that's what its `Content-Type` header is for: it could be text (f.e. HTML) or binary (f.e. a "file") or anything else - see [What are all the possible values for HTTP "Content-Type" header?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48704300/4299358) and [Understanding Content Type in http request and response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54691677/4299358). Of course: you have to actually look at the response (provided it is `HTTP 200` at all and not an error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your post references an API endpoint for uploading files using the retired Dropbox API v1.

If you wish to programmatically create file requests, you should instead use the /2/file_requests/create endpoint on the current Dropbox API v2. You can find the documentation for that here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#file_requests-create

Note that the Dropbox API does not offer the ability to programmatically upload a file to a file request. You can create the file request programmatically as above, but uploading to the file request would be a manual process.